# Strange behavior with MySql database charset

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have Asp.Net Core web application which sits on top ot MySQL database for storage. I'm storing cyrillic letters information in the DB.
The problem appears on the first time i fetch information from the database.
Then the DB returns all chars of the word as QUESTION marks in black diamonts
[image]

When i fetch infromation again it return the correct result:
[image]

And after that the correct answer is provided with any later call. Except if i wait like say 5minutes, then the same behavior occurs.

the Db string i use is:[image]

And the Db Charset info is:

[image]

All tables are with utf8mb4_bin collation

Any ideas how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your table charset and column charset is the same as your Db charset.

Comment: Yes they are the same

Comment: Try changing your charset to utf8mb4. like "xxxxx;Pwd=xxx;CharSet=utf8mb4;"